# Why is ApplicationInitializationCallbackParams sealed?

Tags: c#, uwp

The MSDN documentation states

> "A class that developers should derive from in order to pass
>   information for a custom initialization sequence, in cases where both
>   an Application subclass is present and the entry point Start call is
>   adjusted to pass the information."

But the [ApplicationInitializationCallbackParams](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.applicationinitializationcallbackparams) class is sealed. Why?

Comment: All UWP types are sealed by default, COM does not support implementation inheritance.  The proper word for this is "blunder".  It is otherwise harmless, you don't call Application.Start() yourself.

Answer (score 1):

ApplicationInitializationCallbackParams was introduced along with Windows 8. At the time, it was not sealed. This got changed with the move to WinRT/UWP where you do not implement Application.Start manually, but the documentation was mistakenly not updated.